# What's the cause freezing at 3 methods?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have 3 Threads in a wxPython application. The application hangs at the following three methods:

- [`PIL.Image.open`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm)
- [`ElementTree.write`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write)
- [`time.sleep`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Do you know what could be the common cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's going on exactly, but I'm guessing you're not using wxPython's thread-safe methods to communicate with the GUI. They're wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater, and wx.PostEvent. Don't access the GUI directly.

If these are actually in separate threads, then they shouldn't cause the GUI to hang. I've done the time.sleep() one in a thread on my blog, so I know it doesn't:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

We'll probably need a small, runnable sample app to figure this out: http://wiki.wxpython.org/MakingSampleApps

Comment: I actually had `CallAfter` in my code. I figured out that if I comment out `wx.CallAfter(self._animation_gauge.Pulse)` the application does not hang. I can't understand this.

Comment: I'm not sure either. That looks right. You should ask on the wxPython users group.